# OpenGL: using a single blob of data for ARRAY_BUFFER and ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER

Tags: opengl, gltf

I'm trying to draw a glTF model where all geometry is indexed, e.g.:

```
"meshes": [
{
  "name": "Plane.010",
  "primitives": [
    {
      "attributes": {
        "POSITION": 0,
        "NORMAL": 1,
        "COLOR_0": 2
      },
      "indices": 3, <-- here
      "material": 0
    }
  ]
},
```

But there is only a single buffer defined, and no buffer views specify targets:

```
"buffers": [
    {
        "uri": "data.bin",
        "byteLength": 4518576
    }
]
```

So I send the binary data to the GPU using a single call to `glBufferData` with a VertexArray bound. Now I need to draw the primitives somehow using `glDrawElements`. Is there a way to create an `ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER` and point it to a part of an already loaded buffer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a way to create an `ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER` and point it to a part of an already loaded buffer?

There is no need to, because OpenGL buffer objects aren't *typed* at all. You can bind the same buffer to different binding targets at the same time without any issue, so you can simply bind the same buffer as `ARRAY_BUFFER` and `ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER`. You just need to use the particular byte offsets in your `glDrawElements` calls.

Comment: True, I totally didn't realise that! Thanks